# Does a std::map take an allocator by reference, by value or use it purely as a type?

Tags: c++, dictionary, allocator, c++17

When a `std::map` takes an Allocator as a parameter in a constructor, it takes it by reference with the type taken from its class template parameter:

```
explicit map(const Allocator& alloc);
```

Does it store this reference in the object, or does it take a copy (store it by value), or does it do neither and only use it through the template parameter as a type?  How did you determine this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The allocator is copied into the map.  `std::map` doesn't specify what it does so we fall back to [container.requirements.general]/8 which states:

> [...]All other constructors for these container types take a const allocator_type& argument. [ Note: If an invocation of a constructor uses the default value of an optional allocator argument, then the Allocator type must support value-initialization. — end note ] **A copy of this allocator is used** for any memory allocation and element construction performed, by these constructors and by all member functions, during the lifetime of each container object or until the allocator is replaced.[...]

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>